# Antialiased back buffer error with DirectX 9 and WPF

Tags: wpf, directx, direct3d, antialiasing

I'm trying to use `anti aliasing` in `WPF` and `DirectX 9`.
I'm using the function:

```
d3dImage.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, m_ViewportRenderSurface);
```

but I got this error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in PresentationCore.dll
Additional information: An antialiased back buffer requires a IDirect3DDevice9Ex device.
```

When using `DirectX 9ex` everything works as expected.
Any idea how to make it work with `DirectX 9`?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. See note about multi sampling at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh140978(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks, there is no work around for this?
Its not possible at all to use AA in WPF and D3D9?

Comment: No, there isn't any way to do that. 

For performance reasons, WPF only permits MSAA (multisample antialiasing) when it has D3DCAPS2_CANSHARERESOURCE capability set. 

D3DCAPS2_CANSHARERESOURCE is only possible with 9Ex (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172511(v=vs.85).aspx)